# Re- Setup git-svn repository in Mac after a cleanup

Tags: ssh, osx, git, repository, subversion

I need to re- set up a **password protected, project repository** in my Mac OS X after it was wiped due to hardware issues.

I followed these steps

- Installed the Xcode Command Line version
- Installed Macports using the installer package
- Installed all the other necessary packages
- Installed git-svn

---

Now, I want to use my old ssh keys. Hence I added them to the `~/.ssh` and  set the permissions correctly (`0700` for `~/.ssh`, `0644` for `.pub` and `0600` for the private key). I am uncertain about the next steps to take.
From what I read, I have to add the keys to the ssh-agent by

```
> eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
> ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

I then tried checking out the svn repository by `svn co <repository>` but encountered an error :

```
> svn co <repository> <Directory>
Authentication realm: <repository> Document repository
Password for '<username>':
```

Am I missing any steps?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out after talking to the owners of the code :

- There is an `anonymous` user just to checkout the code. Not permitted to push any changes.
- There is also the specific users who are given the permission to make changes. When I was trying to re-checout the repo, I inadvertently used a different username that wasnt registered. My mistake.
- So, all I did was, defined my `~/.gitconfig`, and checked out the repo with the correct username.